# Why do I get PERMISSION_DENIED on flutter in firestore with public access?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, permission-denied

I'm going nuts on this...

Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{documents=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

flutter code (cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+1):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously()
.then((AuthResult result) async { 
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("users").document("FzI6D1BIvdTU4htj5qeISev8pIo1").get();
  print(snapshot.data.toString());
})
.catchError((error) => print("Firestore error: " + error.toString()));
```

Debug result:

```
W/Firestore(18991): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(users/FzI6D1BIvdTU4htj5qeISev8pIo1) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/flutter (18991): Firestore error: PlatformException(Error performing get, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)
```

- I tried with a valid email + password which successfully signs in; same error.
- In Firestore's "Rules playground", everything works without any PERMISSION_DENIED.
- Document "/users/FzI6D1BIvdTU4htj5qeISev8pIo1" exists but, even if it didn't, It shouldn't fail.

Comment: Try changing `allow read, write;` to `allow read, write: if true;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issues was caused by some admin restrictions in gcloud. If anyone has similar issue, make sure your project's resources are accessible in "IAM & Admin" tab of gcloud's console.

Comment: how gcloud is related to firebase firestore and this issue?

Comment: basically firebase is just a webApp to interact with gcloud, with more ui friendly and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your security rules to allow your signed in users to perform changes in the database.

An example that you can use, to set your security rules to allow authenticated users to perform read and writes is the below one:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I would recommend you to give it a try to use these security rules above and to check the below articles from the official documentation, with more examples and information, on how to configure your security rules.

- [Writing Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rules)
- [Structuring Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: if you looked at the code block, you would see the security rules give public access.

Comment: In my case changing rules didin't help at all.